# Obtener el mayor valor de una tabla mySQL en java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Quiero realizar una consulta que devuelva el mayor codigo en una tabla mySQL. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public class Conexion {
Connection con;

public Conexion() {
    try {
        Class contr = Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    }

    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    }

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection
        ("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/colegio?serverTimezone=UTC","java", "password");
        System.out.println("Conexión con la base de datos exitosa");
    }
    catch(SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println("Error al establecer la conexión");
    }
}

public String getHighestCodigo() {
    String codigo = "0";
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select MAX(codigo) from empleados";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()) {
            codigo = rs.getString("codigo");
        }

        System.out.println("El mayor código es: " + codigo);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado el mayor código");
    }

    return codigo;
}
```

Si quito el bucle while sigue dando error así que interpreto que el fallo está en la línea

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Pero no se cómo solucionarlo. log:

run:

Conexión con la base de datos exitosa

No se ha encontrado el mayor código

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)

Comment: Pon el stacktrace para que podamos ver que dice el error e indica la línea que lo lanza.

Comment: vale, he encontrado el problema: soy retrasado y estaba accediendo a la base de datos incorrecta